# Removing Sensitive Data From Github using GUI?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I accidentally uploaded a bunch of very sensitive client projects to Github. I need to remove them immediately.

I'm very new to Git. I don't know how to use the terminal. I'm using Github Desktop on Mac. Can someone please explain it to me in the simplest terms possible how to quickly and effectively purge/remove full directories from a GitHub repository's history without using terminal? (or very very simple specific instructions on how to use terminal to do this?)

I found some terminal directions already through Google, but I don't know how to use it. I can't find any option on github.com to do it via browser, and the Desktop app doesn't seem to allow history of files or directories.

Comment: No.. I don't understand how to use the terminal codes... I want to just right click in the desktop app and hit "purge".. is there some kind of option that doesn't involve a week of learning how to use terminal?

Comment: Are you trying to delete individual commits, or whole repositories?

Comment: I accidentally copied a folder full of sensitive client files to my github repository directory on my desktop. I hit commit without realizing the files were there. Github uploaded everything. I did a second commit to try to remove them not realizing they would still be sitting in the repository history. Now I can't figure out how to purge them completely from history.

Comment: You have set the repository to priveate already I assume, right? That's doable from github.

Comment: Yes, I stopped panicking because I realized the repo was already set to private, so low risk of it being publicly exposed. Still makes me uneasy that it's sitting on a server somewhere.. I might just purge the entire repo and start over. I'm kind of surprised there isn't a "simple" way to undo an accidental sensitive commit that doesn't involve terminal.

Comment: @Cmaxster Git is a command line utility and if you want to use all its features you need to learn to use it in a terminal. No graphical front-end is complete.